# Why should I use 'the' before 'phone' but 'a' before 'voice message' in these sentences?

Tags: articles

If I write the sentence below without an article, it will be wrong, and the article required is definite (*the*):

> **[1a]** *****​May I use phone in your office?
>   **[1b]** May I use **the** phone in your office?

If I write *message* without an article, it will also be wrong, but the article required will be indefinite (*a*).

> **[2a]** *****​I will leave voice message.
>   **[2b]** I will leave **a** voice message.

Why are 1a is wrong and 1b is correct? What is the difference between 2a and 2b?

Comment: I have edited your question quite a bit. Please make sure that the rephrasing asks the questions you want answered.

Comment: Thank you deadrat and sumelic. Yes it is still the correct question I had asked. Let's wait for clear answer of this question

Comment: The phone already exists. The message does not yet.

Comment: The difference between 1b and 2b, is simply that people receive multiple voice messages, thus necessitating the indefinite article when speaking of just one of them. But usually they have only one phone, calling for the definite. If there were several phones in the office, you might say ***a phone in your office***. Or if you were referring to people with phones, you could use the indefinite - e.g. *I just heard **a phone** ring somewhere*.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se]

Comment: Similarly, if there is a particular message you are waiting to be given, someone might let you know that they had "*...left **the** message on your  answer machine".*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May I use the phone in your office?

Once you establish the context of *your office*, you can use *the* with anything that can reasonably be expected to be found in and/or associated with the office: the chair (in your office), the desk (in your office), the phone (in your office), the floor (in your office), etc.

As for

> I will leave a voice message.

You use *a* because you are leaving one voice message among many possible voice messages. You don't assume your hearer can identify *which* voice message you are talking about, other than it is *one* that you will leave.

On the other hand, you can say

> I will leave the voice message.

if you expect that the person you are talking to can identify *which* voice message you are talking about. Maybe it's one you have talked about before, maybe it's one that the person who you are calling told you to leave. This is similar to

> I will forward you the voice message

or

> Do you wanna listen to the voice message?

With *the*, you assume that the person you are talking to can identify *which* voice message you are talking about. If you don't assume that, than you'd likely use *a* in these sentences.